# PHP letter value in For Loop

Tags: php, string, variables

I am having problems with my PHP code, I am trying to display a string with a value. For example, `A = 1`, `B = 2`. So if I had a string value of `Cat`, it would display a value of `3120` and also would add all the values together.

Many Thanks,

Jonathan

Comment: Show the code..

Comment: `for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) { echo ord(strtoupper($string[$i])) - 64; }`

Comment: Think your looking for something like this: http://ideone.com/OgCDs4

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ord()` to get `ASCII` value and subtract `96`. Example:

```
$str = 'cat';
$val = strtolower($str);
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){
    echo ord($val[$i]) - 96;
}
```

`strtolower()` to convert lower case latter.

Comment: This is the right way to do it if you know that the input will always be a single word with no spaces, numbers or special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Create an associative array. Keys should be the letters, and values should store the values.
Get the letters, and get the value, and concat them into a new string:

```
$string = 'Cab';
$lettersArray = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3,
    //and so on
);
$valueString = '';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
    $letter = strtolower(substr($string,$i,1));
    $valueString .= $lettersArray[$letter];
}
echo $valueString;
```

Output is:

```
312
```

Comment: Test your code! it doesn't work even! (strtolower();<--)

Answer (score 0):

Organize letter and value in a array

```
$letters = array(
'a' => 1
, 'b' => 2
, ...
);
```

loop the string

```
$string = "cat";

$sum = 0;

for($i = 0; i<strlen($string);$i++) {
   $index = $string[$i];
   $sum += $letters[$index];
   print $letters[$index];

}
```

finally, print the sum

```
print $sum;
```